# C : Unable to assign a string of a struct to an array

Tags: c

I'm basically extracting strings from an Excel file to store them in an array. I'm facing an issue assigning them to my array.

This is a line of the excel file:

```
Beutegier;Jack Ketchum;Heyne;2009;3453675622
```

This is a part of my function:

```c
buecher[*num_buch].autor            = NULL;
buecher[*num_buch].titel            = strdup(strtok(linebuf, delim)); //Works correctly 
char *str1 = strtok(NULL, delim); //This extracts the name which is : Jack Ketchum
buecher[*num_buch].autor->name      = strdup(str1); //Program crashes here
```

This my struct :

```c
typedef struct {
    char *name;                   /* Zeiger auf vollstdg. Namen dieses Autors */
    unsigned short anz_buecher;   /* Anzahl der Bücher dieses Autors */
} Autor;
    
/* Struktur einer Buch-Definition */
typedef struct {
    char *titel;                     /* Zeiger auf Titelstring */
    Autor *autor;                    /* Zeiger auf Element des Autoren-arrays */
    Verlag *verlag;                  /* Zeiger auf Element des Verlage-arrays */
    unsigned short erscheinungsjahr; /* Jahreszahl 4-stellig, z. B.: 2009 */
    char *isbn;                      /* Zeiger auf ISBN-string */
} Buch;
```

I don't know why the program is crashing in that line. I almost did the same thing with the first line and it worked correctly there.

Comment: Did you initialize `buecher[*num_buch].autor`? Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: No I didn't , should I initialize it ?

Comment: Yes, of course. Dereferencing uninitialized pointer is a bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is due to `autor` being a `NULL` pointer:

```
buecher[*num_buch].autor            = NULL;
```

followed by an attempt to store through it:

```
buecher[*num_buch].autor->name      = strdup(str1);
```

This attempts to set the `name` field of the `Autor` structure pointer to by `autor`.  But that is just a `NULL` pointer, and there is no `Autor` structure, hence no `name` field to store to.

You can fix it by changing the first assignment to:

```
buecher[*num_buch].autor            = malloc(sizeof(Autor));
```

It would also be good practice to check the value returned by `malloc` to make sure it isn't `NULL`.

Don't forget that you later need to free the storage returned by `malloc`, `strdup`, etc. to avoid memory leaks.